# Masking A Website URL

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, adsense

I was conducting a little experiment using frames in a website where basically I want to open up one url inside another - So for example http://www.wewbsitea.com would show up when you go to http://www.websiteb.com.

Using a frameset this works perfectly, however when testing the analytics I found that it is working but the url that it shows is for websiteB & not websiteA, which I guess makes sense as that is the url in the address bar.

I was just wondering if there was actually a way to make it show up as websiteA in the Analytics code?

Also, does this effect your adsense in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Frames provide an isolation barrier. no code running in the frameset can access framed content from another domain, neiter vice versa. else all sorts of horrible XSS attacks would be possible..

Comment: Thanks - How about Adsense, if someone clicked an advert link would I get paid?

Comment: you'd get paid the same as if you redirected them to the framed site, I don't know the rules for adsense.

Answer (score 0):

While Jasen is right that interaction between frames on different domains is not really possible (especially if you do not control both sites) you can make it *look* like you tracked the framed page - Universal Analytic has a "set" method which allows you to override the default values. So something like

```
ga('set', 'hostname', 'websiteb.com');
ga('set', 'page', '/framedpage.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

should make things *look* like you were actually tracking the frames site (this is as per documentation, I have not tested this). I frankly don't quite see you use case and I don't think products connected to your Analytics account (Adwords, Adsense, GWT) would be fooled (that would need to be tested, though).